# Amazon Redshift Copy Command invalid characters

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

[image]

Im trying to copy the above data from SQL Server to Amazon Redshift.
Unfortunately I found that the characters in ***catdesc*** column are replaced by '?'(i.e., question mark).

[image]

Can any one suggest on this?

Comment: Do you know what encoding is used in catdesc column? Is it utf-8? gbk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redshift should be able to load in UTF8 characters, you need to use the VARCHAR data type with enough space to handle the multibyte characters.

There's some more information here: [Loading Multibyte Data from Amazon S3](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_loading_unicode_data.html) and here: [Handling UTF-8 Characters in Redshift](https://www.flydata.com/blog/handling-utf-8-characters-in-redshift/)